# Excel RANDBETWEEN as a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

How does one use a string value as a random value, I have 3 values namely SMS, Datasynergy and Other, i want to simulate live data by using the random function to assign one of the aforementioned value to my field at random?

The way i thought of it is to make a random value between 1-3 and and then go on to say if 1 = SMS else if 2 = Datasynergy else Other

But im pretty sure there must be other ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,3),"SMS","Datasynergy","Other")
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use INDEX, e.g.

`=INDEX({"SMS","Datasynergy","Other"},RANDBETWEEN(1,3))`

which you can easily adapt for a longer list like this

`=INDEX(List,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(List)))`