# Excel Random number from a set of options

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In MS Excel, how can I randomly calculate a number number that is from one of a set of 5 options?

For example, in cell B1 I would like to have a random number that is either 15,30,50,75, or 100.

I would like a completely random output of these 5 numbers in cells B1:B100.

I was thinking that I could generate a random number in cell A1 using rand, then using a series of > or < IF statements to output only one of these numbers above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel RANDBETWEEN as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077013/excel-randbetween-as-a-string)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This formula will do it:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),15,30,50,75,100)
```

If you want to use a range of cells:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,RANDBETWEEN(1,5))
```

Comment: CHOOSE was the perfect solution for me in this case. +1 for the alternative when I may have a range of cells. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A quick and easy way would be to first make a lookup list like this:

[image]

Then in your column do a formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(ROUND(RAND()*10,0),$A$7:$B$16,1,FALSE)
```

where the `$A$7:$B$16` is where your list is at. It can be on a different tab, or separate file, if you really need to isolate it.

You could also create a custom VBA function too, but I think that is beyond what you are looking for.

Comment: hehe.. three solutions posted all at once. I like Doug's better than mine. Upvoted it!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have filled rows 1-5 in row G of a spreadsheet with the values you want to randomly display. You can use `=INDIRECT("G"&RANDBETWEEN(1,5))` to display any one of those randomly.

`INDIRECT` lets you reference a cell using a string.
Since you want cells "G1" - "G5", we start of with "G".
& combines "G" with the value of the next function.
Then the RANDBETWEEN function will give us a number between the two parameters we provide (in this case 1 through 5).

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: This is way simpler than the other answers, though I don't think it's reliable  in "production" or any large-scale spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the right syntax for me was like this:

`=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;7);500;525;550;575;600;625;650)`

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
=SMALL({array containing numbers},RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT({array containing numbers})))
```

e.g. if you have an array containing the 5 numbers you want to use in `$B$2:$B$6`

```
=SMALL($B$2:$B$6,RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNT($B$2:$B$6)))
```

This returns a random position in the list of numbers, with the total frequency of numbers being defined size of the array.