# pop a random value from a list of cells

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I have a question that is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223413/excel-random-number-from-a-set-of-options), but a little different:

Let's say I have data like this:

```
CAR NAME   COLOR  LIST OF COLORS
Car1         ?        Red
Car2         ?        Blue
Car3         ?        Green
Car4         ?        Black
```

and I want to randomly distribute all of the colors to all of the cars without repetition, i.e.

```
CAR NAME   COLOR  LIST OF COLORS
Car1       Green        Red
Car2       Black        Blue
Car3       Blue         Green
Car4       Red          Black
```

Is there a way to have a cell randomly select from a list excluding values already input in another range?

Comment: You need to use VBA to perform this efficiently. A formula can iterate but native worksheet formulas do not handle undetermined scope well.

Comment: Add a column with `=RAND()` to the right of "List of Colors" and sort the two columns on the new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **D2** enter:

```
=RAND()
```

and copy down.  In **B2** enter:

```
=INDEX(C$2:C$5,MATCH(LARGE(D$2:D$5,ROW()-1),D$2:D$5,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to shuffle the array. It's fairly easy to do in JavaScript.

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

```
shuffle = function(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    // rotate array vertical
    var vArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
      vArray.push([o[i]]);
    }
    return vArray;
}
```

Example with spreadsheet:

http://dtab.io/sheets/560b7f5d457aff1e1fe625d2